# I'm getting a type error while using list.map function

Tags: dart

I'm getting a type error when running the following code in DartPad.

```
void main() {
  List<int> list = [10, 20, 30];
  List<int> squares = list.map((x) => x * x);
  squares.forEach((x) => print(x));
}
```

Getting the following error

```
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Instance of 'MappedListIterable<int, int>': 
type 'MappedListIterable<int, int>' is not a subtype of 
type 'List<int>'
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> squares = list.map((x) => x * x);
```

would need to be

```
List<int> squares = list.map((x) => x * x).toList();
```

`map()` returns an `Iterable`, not a `List`